# Bind object to winForms control element

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a class named OrganizerNote with fields: `public long id; public DateTime CreationDate; public string Title; public string Note;`

Also I have a class `public class XMLOrganizer` that has 1 field:
`public List<OrganizerNote> Notes=new List<OrganizerNote>();`

For example, I have several objects:

```
OrganizerNote n1 = new OrganizerNote();
OrganizerNote n2 = new OrganizerNote();
```

with some data in fields.
Then I create 1 object

```
XMLOrganizer xmlOrg = new XMLOrganizer();
xmlOrg.Notes.Add(n1);
xmlOrg.Notes.Add(n2);
```

So I need to bind each  xmlOrg.Notes[0] ... xmlOrg.Notes[i] to Row[i] in datagridView control. And fields values would be in columns.

How could I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make

```
List<OrganizerNote> Notes=new List<OrganizerNote>();
```

into

```
BindingList<OrganizerNote> Notes=new BindingList<OrganizerNote>();
```

and then create a binding source on the form bind that to the database and then set the binding datasource to the Notes field on the XMLOranizer